# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyProjectName/myvideo1.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in Android 11

Tags: java, android, file

I have an app like tiktok where users can upload there video by recording them on camera. My code is working fine till Android 10. But whenever I am running my app on Android 11, I am getting this exception.
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.project/myvideo1.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Manifest File-[image: Manifest file]

[image: Exception]

Comment: Can you tell what your app does when your app gets that exception?

Comment: Please remove images and post code and logcat as text.

Comment: Use `FileProvider`

Comment: @blackapps recording video

Comment: That is a not to the point answer that does not help at all. But worse: you dit not read the second comment.

Comment: @SoubhagyaSwain storage access permissions are changed in Android 11,I would suggest u read the docs to understand the new storage access framework.